# How to add custom SOAP header for C# Web service client invoke Axis 1.4 Web service

Tags: c#, java, web-services, axis, webservice-client

I'm trying to write a C# application that's a Webservice client that invokes a Java Web service (using Axis 1.4), but I can't get it to work.
Java WS requires a custom SOAP header for authentication, so I added one to my C# application. The code generated in VS 2010 doesn't include a SOAP header, so I add a `MySOAPHeader` class into the project:

```
namespace AddProvinceCityDemo
{
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://service.itthrm.vnitt.org")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("securitytoken", Namespace = "http://service.itthrm.vnitt.org", IsNullable = false)]
    public class MySOAPHeader:SoapHeader
    {
        public String username;
        public String password;
    }
}
```

I also altered the generated code in Reference.cs by adding a `MySOAPHeader` variable

```
public partial class ProvinceServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<AddProvinceCityDemo.ProvinceService.ProvinceService>, AddProvinceCityDemo.ProvinceService.ProvinceService {

        public MySOAPHeader customSOAPHeader;
        public ProvinceServiceClient() {
        }
         //.........................
}
```

Finally, I invoked WS with the following code:

```
MySOAPHeader authentication = new MySOAPHeader();
 authentication.username = username;

  authentication.password = encryptedpass;
 //end set SOAP header information

 ProvinceServiceClient provinceservice = new ProvinceServiceClient();

 provinceservice.customSOAPHeader = authentication;
 Province[] arrprovince = null;

 arrprovince = provinceservice.findAll();
```

But it ends up throwing an error: `"Failed to retrieve the SOAP header"`.

It was easy to write a Java version of the code:

```
SOAPHeaderElement oHeaderElement;

oHeaderElement = new SOAPHeaderElement(namespace, "securityHeader");
oHeaderElement.setPrefix"sec");
oHeaderElement.setMustUnderstand(false);
oElement = oHeaderElement.addChildElement("username");
oElement.addTextNode(username);
oElement = oHeaderElement.addChildElement("password");
oElement.addTextNode(passwordEncrypt);
```

How can I do the same in .NET and C#?

Comment: Your `new ProvinceServiceClient()` call should include a method like a `GetSecurityEnpointAddress()` method in the second parameter.